# How Do I open different views based on url in django

Tags: python, django

I'm just starting to use django so bear with me. 
I'm currently trying to open different template based on the url I got , for example
 `path("<int:pk>",views.OptionView.as_view(),name = 'eachoption')`
What I want to do is to open a different view based on the value of the pk I got , I've searched for a while but still got no luck, can anyone help me ? :/

Comment: You need to write this login in `OptionView`. Return different template based on the pk you receive.

Comment: Are you looking for the url link?

Answer (score 0):

```
# you can get the id parameter value in your class, action accordingly

class OptionView(TemplateView):
    template_name = '...template_name..' 
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.GET.get('pk') == 1:
        # your action for id 1
        elif request.GET.get('pk') == 2:
        # your action for id 2
        else:
        # your default action
    ....
```

Comment: Thanks! One more question, is it possible to change the template I'm using? like
```if request.GET.get('pk') == 1:
        template_name = 'template_to_use_for_this_case'
```